# Can you prove this law? without using vector properties

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Can you prove the parallelogram law, which states that,

The sum of square of sides of a parallelogram=The sum of square of the diagonals

without using vector properties.

Comment: Isn't this just a basic application of Pythagoras' Theorem? Or does that somehow constitute using vector properties?

Comment: @LogicBeDamned can you please answer it then maybe the solution is just not clicking me.

Comment: This property is equivalent for spaces with norm to be Euclidean and, generally, we don't call their elements vectors.

Comment: @trula By sides, I mean all of the sides, not just the different sides :)

Comment: Because every Euclidean space (i.e. space with scalar product) have this property, then enough is to proof reverse. Proof is based on following definition: for two $f,g$ elements of space with norm let's define scalar product with $(f,g)=\frac{1}{4}(|| f+g ||^2+ | f-g ||^2)$. Then we need to proof all properties of scalar product.

Comment: @zkutch Thanks for clarifying :) moreover having an expert like you answering my question is really a blessing :)

Comment: Why had you enclosed the whole thing in \$\$?